# Jquery stop working when setTimeout is added

Tags: javascript, jquery

I cannot seem to have a series of functions delayed by 2s using setTimeout. It simply stops any of the code from executing. I believe the syntax is correct and everything works as expected when the setTimeout is removed. If anyone can help, I would be very grateful. Thank you.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        var x = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 991px)");
        var navThree = window.innerHeight * 0.08;
        var navToo = window.innerHeight * 0.1;
        $('.FeatureExpand').click(function() {
            setTimeout(function() {
            $(this).find(".Feature_1-1").toggleClass("Feature_1-1-Expanded Feature_1-1-Contracted")
            $(this).find(".featureTitle_1 ").toggleClass("title-Collapsed title-Expanded")
            $(this).find(".FeatureDescription-L").toggleClass("extendLeft-Expanded extendLeft prodFeature_1-des prodFeature_1-des-Expanded")
            $(this).find(".FeatureDescription-R").toggleClass("extendRight-Expanded extendRight prodFeature_1-des prodFeature_1-des-Expanded")
            $(this).find(".featureCopy").toggleClass("featureCopy-show featureCopy-hide")
            $(this).find(".Feature_1-img").toggleClass("img-Collapsed img-Expanded")
            $(this).find(".logoSplash, .hamSplash").toggleClass("splash40vh splash15vh")
            $(this).find(".FeatureSpacer").toggleClass("splash40vh splash15vh")
            $(this).find(".FeatureContent").toggleClass("FChidden FCshow")
            $(this).find(".FCpair").toggleClass("FCpair-hide FCpair-show")
            $(this).find(".feature-icon-left").toggleClass("feature-icon-left-Collapsed feature-icon-left-Expanded")
            $(".Feature_1-1").bind("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd", function(){ Waypoint.refreshAll() });
            if (x.matches) {
              $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $(this).offset().top - navThree});
                }
              else {
              $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $(this).offset().top - navToo});
                }
            }, 2000 );
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your help! Seems that when the fat arrow (=>) is added correctly, the issue is fixed. Here's the new code.

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var x = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 991px)");
        var navThree = window.innerHeight * 0.08;
        var navToo = window.innerHeight * 0.1;

        $('.FeatureExpand').click(function() {
            if (x.matches) {
              $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $(this).offset().top - navThree});
                }
              else {
              $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $(this).offset().top - navToo});
                };
                
            setTimeout(() => {
            $(this).find(".Feature_1-1").toggleClass("Feature_1-1-Expanded Feature_1-1-Contracted")
            $(this).find(".featureTitle_1 ").toggleClass("title-Collapsed title-Expanded")
            $(this).find(".FeatureDescription-L").toggleClass("extendLeft-Expanded extendLeft prodFeature_1-des prodFeature_1-des-Expanded")
            $(this).find(".FeatureDescription-R").toggleClass("extendRight-Expanded extendRight prodFeature_1-des prodFeature_1-des-Expanded")
            $(this).find(".featureCopy").toggleClass("featureCopy-show featureCopy-hide")
            $(this).find(".Feature_1-img").toggleClass("img-Collapsed img-Expanded")
            $(this).find(".logoSplash, .hamSplash").toggleClass("splash40vh splash15vh")
            $(this).find(".FeatureSpacer").toggleClass("splash40vh splash15vh")
            $(this).find(".FeatureContent").toggleClass("FChidden FCshow")
            $(this).find(".FCpair").toggleClass("FCpair-hide FCpair-show")
            $(this).find(".feature-icon-left").toggleClass("feature-icon-left-Collapsed feature-icon-left-Expanded")
            $(".Feature_1-1").bind("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd", function(){ Waypoint.refreshAll() });
            }, 1000 );
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are losing `this` inside the anonymous function, so `$(this)` is not defined or referred to something else...
before calling setTimeout, try

```
var that = $(this);
setTimeout(function() {
    that.find(...)
},1000);
```

Comment: Alternatively, replace `function() { ...` with an arrow function like `() => { ...` so the value of `this` doesn't change

Comment: Thank you, that did solve the issue in question however I am now faced with the variable selecting all of the found classes instead of the ones nested in the selected div.

Comment: hm... technically it should pass variable "that" which links to specific element which was clicked on... Is it right before setTimeout? Must be inside the "click" function